# selenium python script working half the time

Tags: python, selenium

I wrote a selenium based test in Python which authenticates to a web page and if the page loads up with 3 html canvas, then the web page is working fine but on the 5th or 6th time, it starts to fail. I do see errors in my geckodriver log which is:

```
[GFX1-]: Receive IPC close with reason=AbnormalShutdown
[Child 16704] WARNING: pipe error (3): Connection reset by peer: file   /builds/slave/m-rel-l64-  00000000000000000000/build/src/ipc/chromium/src/chrome/common/ipc_channel_ posix.cc, line 320
[Child 16704] ###!!! ABORT: Aborting on channel error.: file   /builds/slave/m-rel-l64-   00000000000000000000/build/src/ipc/glue/MessageChannel.cpp, line 2056
[Child 16704] ###!!! ABORT: Aborting on channel error.: file   /builds/slave/m-rel-l64-  00000000000000000000/build/src/ipc/glue/MessageChannel.cpp, line 2056
```

I also get the error below in syslog regardless if it passes or fails.

```
kernel: [3900922.779114] Chrome_ChildThr[16007]: segfault at 0 ip 000000000040782b sp 00007fc7558fe2b0 error 6 in plugin-container[400000+67000]
```

This is on ubuntu 14.04, I do have Xvfb running and I have exported my DISPLAY=10.